# Generating dynamic routes in Nuxt with Cloud Firestore using @nuxtjs/firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

I need some help.

I'm trying to build out my static site on Nuxt which has a bunch of dynamic routes.

So far in my nuxt.config.js I've got

```
generate: {
   async routes() {
   const queryDb = await app.$fire.firestore.collection("schools").get()
   return queryDb.docs.map(x => `/performance/${x.schoolId}`);
  }
}
```

However, when using Nuxt generate, it fails because it can't read property '$fire' which is how I've been accessing firebase throughout my application (using https://firebase.nuxtjs.org). Is there some way I can require it before creating the routes?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$fire' of undefined

After following this [demo of Nuxt and Firebase](https://github.com/lupas/nuxt-firebase-demo), it fixed by adding `'@nuxtjs/firebase'` inside the `buildModules` that didn't mention from the [tutorial](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/):

**nuxt.config.js**

```
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/firebase'
],
```